# How to rename path in response for populate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have a query like this:

```
galleryModel.find({_id: galleryId})
            .populate({
                model: 'User',
                path: 'objectId',
                select: 'firstName lastName'
            })
```

End response for `objectId` will be like this:

```
objectId: {
...
}
```

How can I change it to `user` in response without changing real path?

Comment: did you solved it?

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by virtual populate, introduced in mongoose version 4.5 . For that you need to define a virtual field in mongoose schema.

```
var GallerySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    objectId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
    },
});

GallerySchema.virtual('user', {
    ref: 'User',
    localField: 'objectId', 
    foreignField: '_id' 
});
```

Ans when you run find  query, just populate it with user.

```
Gallry.find({_id: galleryId}).populate('user','firstName lastName').exec(function(error, gallery) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(gallery);;
});
```

Above code is not tested in program, there may be typos, You can get more details about mongoose virtual populate on below link

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: This works, but I needed to execute the populate separated from the query using `data = await Model.findOne({...})`and `data.populate("name", {key: 1}).execPopulate()`, and as you can see I'm not using a string to define the attributes that are gonna be retrieved / async await

Comment: Also don't forget to add `toJSON: { virtuals: true }` in your schema options object, otherwise, the virtuals won't get sent in the JSON response of a API http request.